# Calendar view issue in tabs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, sharepoint-calendar

I would like to display multiple calendar views in tabs. I am using jQuery for tabbing.

If I set display `none` to other tabs, other calendar will not load all items or if I apply `ms-hidden` class to other tabs, it will change position of items.

[image]

Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: My below comment is working for SharePoint 2010

Comment: Have you applied any `float`, `margin` or `padding` CSS to your wrapper element of the calendar? If you are stretching width with your own CSS, that might be causing the issue in calculating the width of the item. Check more with the help of Developer Tools.

Comment: Hello @Pradip R., I have not applied any css on that.Whenever i click on other tab,it will automatically change inline css (margin left and width) of calendar list item of previous tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. I have called 'MoveToDate' javascript function of SharePoint calendar next previous button on tab click event. Now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

For those interested, I found a work around.

Basically, instead of showing/hiding tabs, I treated it more like a carousel (or a slider). I essentially allow all of my tabs be visible and wrap them with a container. I set the height of the container and hide the overflow, so you can only actually see one at a time. This is a less extreme idea from what I described in my question. I can't speak to why that didn't work, but this solution did, but the idea is essentially the same: don't hide the calendars in the DOM, simply make only one of them them visible to the user; doing it that way allows the SP JavaScript to make the proper calculation for the event items.

I wrote up a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2LAs/2/) that shows a simplistic version of what I did (my code is a little more complicated). Here's the basic DOM structure:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li data-tabid="tab1">Tab One</li>
        <li data-tabid="tab2">Tab Two</li>
        <li data-tabid="tab3">Tab Three</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="tab1">Tab 1</div>
            <div id="tab2">Tab 2</div>
            <div id="tab3">Tab 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you @hardik patel for your reply.I am working on SharePoint 2013. I have tried easy tab solution and applied ms-hidden class, but not give proper look (List item position).

Comment: I have updated my answer... Please check it.

Comment: Hello @Hardik, i have tried this solution, but not working. I found the problem, i append webpart to dynamic generated div using jquery, after append it, it will change the css of calendar list item of inactive tabs.